# JMeter adds WWW and .com to URL while recording

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Recently i faced some issues while record/playback in Apache JMeter v 3.1.

While recording a site with url(http://10.221.50.121:9500), JMeter adds `www` and `.com` to the URL making it as `http://www.10.221.50.121.com:9500`. How to stop JMeter from adding it (or) remove the `www` and `.com` prefixes/suffixes in the recorded URL.

I Would really appreciate if someone helps me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour using local Tomcat deployment on port 9500 and [manager application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html). I am not also able to found any sign of adding `.com` substring in [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.com&type=) so probably something is wrong either with your application or JMeter recording configuration.

Consider following options:

1. Upgrading to [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32). Newer JMeter versions normally come with bug fixes, performance improvements and of course new features.
2. Preparing JMeter for recording using [Templates feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building), from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Template -> Recording -> Create`
3. Use [Firefox browser for recording](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) (don't install any add-ins). Firefox has separate (not system-wide) proxy configuration, this way you will be sure that nothing else stands between browser and JMeter during recording process.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll recheck once again my configuration and I will comeback with result after upgrading.